# What is the Most Suitable NoSQL database which statisfies following conditions?

Tags: database, nosql

- Suitable for Heavy Load
- More Efficient
- Faster

(It is better if you can provide the reasons & justifications)

Comment: All databases SQL or NoSQL would have these characteristics. We need other info as data type (documental, graph or BigTable style), if you want write a lot and read a litle or the opposite... talking about  CAP (consinstency, availability, partition tollerance) which of these aspects can you give up?  Have you ever read  anything about NoSQL?

Comment: I have read all the above..This is not an actual project. I just have to do a research for a system with heavy load.